# How to? CSS "Position:Absolute" constant Margin-Top? Possible?

Tags: html, css, css-position

This question sounds simple, but I'm an expert with CSS and I'm thinking it's impossible (a RARE thing).

Is it possible to use CSS to give a `<div>` a constant top margin if that `<div>` has no background (e.g. you can see through it)?

Basically, I want the background image to be visible in the top 100px of a site, so that even when scrolling down, that top-margin remains in place.

You can look at some live code here:
http://www.codemyconcepthq.com/projects/2453/

Here's a little infographic of what I'm attempting to do:
http://cl.ly/40bD

Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain this question in other terms? i'm having a hard time since i believe it's been solved already...

Comment: Notice in the infographic how the logo goes behind the top navbar?  Well it's not supposed to do that.  Rather, it should disappear completely.  This can be done with a margin-top on the right-side containing DIV but the problem is that when you scroll the logo goes behind the navbar which is what I'm trying to avoid.  I'm looking for a "sticky" top margin.

Comment: I think the way you do this normally is just make the top navbar non-transparent.  One approach would be to wrap the content box and set `overflow: scroll` and then make sure the rest of the page doesn't exceed 100% browser height (so you don't end up with two scrollbars).

Comment: [Please don't use URL shorteners on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shorting-services/64509#64509) This isn't Twitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution you could try is to cut the top of the background (this image: http://www.codemyconcepthq.com/projects/2453/images/bg-body.png) and you set it as the background of your header.

So when you scroll down, the content will go under your header and you will not see that content because your header will have a background.

**Edit:**

Instead of cutting the background like I said, just set the background of your header to the same image used for the main background. That will prevent the browser from having to download two images (which is useless because the images are the same).

Comment: Beautiful!  This is exactly what I was looking for, I just could NOT think of it!  Magnifique!  

I'll just do an absolute positioned top center DIV that uses the same background image top-center (load only once), and has a z-index HIGHER than the right-side content and LOWER than the navbar!!!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, I think the best you can do is pop another `<div>` `<div id="header">`, apply the `<body>`’s background image to `<div id="header">`, and then apply your translucent image to the `<div>` you put inside. Then the scrolling content will then be hidden by `<div id="header">`’s new background.

So, HTML:

```
<div id="header"><!-- Begin Header -->
    <div id="header-inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#header {
    background:url("../images/bg-body.png") no-repeat fixed center top #000000;
}

#header-inner {
    background:url("../images/bg-menu.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: ahhhh!  That's exactly what Marc said... I had to give it to him since he answered first... LOL! Look at my comment on his just before I saw your answer here!

Comment: Yup — I answered slower because I included working code in mine :) Naw, glad you got a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect by placing a non-transparent background that is exactly the same as the background behind the header part, in the very same area, and have the content (#wrapper in your case?) go behind that.